# Reference on a result about integral closures.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Could you please give a reference or a sketch of a proof for the following proposition?

> **Proposition:** The integral closure of a complete local Noetherian domain $R$ is module-finite over $R$

You can find the statement [here](http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/trieste.pdf), at pag. 4 (12).

Comment: The first entry by googling: https://books.google.ro/books?id=APPtnn84FMIC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=integral+closure+of+a+complete+local+Noetherian+domain&source=bl&ots=2NbJdXbFU0&sig=ntHnm_26SAVv6QweJYnxKHfF7NA&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilsNWhssHMAhXBjywKHRMfAOoQ6AEIEzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false. Of course, you could have also done this.

Comment: Thank you... I didn't find anything by using  google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You even have more:

> **Nagata's theorem:**
>
> Every complete local noetherian domain is a japanese ring.

Which means such a ring is a noetherian integral domain with the property that its integral closure in a finite extension of its field of fractions is module finite.

You'll find a proof in Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra Ch. IX, *Complete local noetherian rings*, § 4, no 2, theorem 2.